# Sum and product of two non-Borel measurable functions being Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

Can we find an example of non-Borel-measurable functions say $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ such that both $\phi_1+\phi_2$ and $\phi_1\phi_2$ are Borel measurable?

I can't think of any, appreciate any help!

Comment: Take $\phi_1$ the characteristic function of a non-measurable set, $\phi_2=1-\phi_1$.

Comment: Okay, so $\phi_1$ could be something like $\phi_1(x)=\mathbb{1}_{C(x)+x}(x)$ right? where $C$ is the cantor function? I'm not sure, could you elaborate a bit? @AndrésE.Caicedo

Comment: Or: let $\phi_1\colon X\to\{\pm 1\}$ be nonmeasurable and $\phi_2=-\phi_1$.  Then $\phi_1+\phi_2$ is constant $0$ and $\phi_1\phi_2$ is constant $-1$.

Comment: @user10354138, but what can be an explicit $\phi_1$? I'm confused about that

Comment: @user440024 take for example the characteristic function $\phi_1 = \mathbb{1}_V$, where $V$ is the Vitali set.